# Whole packet length Scapy

Tags: python, wireshark, packet, scapy

I am capturing WiFi traffic with tcpdump using the parameter `-s 100` (which means I am only capturing the headers of the packets).

When I load the .pcap file and process it with Scapy I do:

```
pkts = rdpcap(pcapfile)
totalbytes = 0
for pkt in pkts:
    totalbytes += len(pkt)
```

However, as I am truncating the capture, doing `len(pkt)` will not give me the whole packet length (**frame length**), it will give me the **captured packet length**. How can I get the real packet length?

*Extra*: as I have done in some occasions before, I open the pcap file in **wireshark** and search for the hex values of interest. But in this case (**frame.len**) will show the value I am looking for, but I can't find the way wireshark obtains this real packet length without having the whole packet captured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rdpcap` function uses the `PcapReader` class for reading packets. Unfortunately this class discards the information you are looking for in the `read_packet` method, even though it is to be found in the pcap file. So you have to use the `RawPcapReader` directly.

```
totalbytes = 0
for pkt, (sec, usec, wirelen) in RawPcapReader(pcapfile):
    totalbytes += wirelen
```

Comment: Amazing Helmut! Thanks so much! No info at all searching like crazy. I hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use RawPcapReader, you can use the `len` attribute for IPv4 packets.

```
real_length = pkt[IP].len
truncated_length = len(pkt)
```

Strangely, the IPv6 layer in Scapy doesn't have the same  attribute, but it does have an attribute called `plen` which is the length of the payload:

```
payload_length = pkt[IPv6].plen
real_length = payload_length + 40
truncated_length = len(pkt)
```

Answer (score 0):

With modern Scapy versions, the proper answer would be to use `pkt.wirelen`. This only exists in packets read from a pcap